# How to check if mapbox layer is ready?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How do I check that a Mapbox raster layer is displayed on the map?

My goal is to stop a loading animation. I know I can check if the map itself is ready.

```
map.on('ready', someFunction)
```

How do I do something like this but for a specific layer?

Answer (score 1):

There are events for when pieces of data load https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#mapdataevent, but unfortunately not for when all loading is complete.

Comment: It would great to see an example of how to use this functionality :)

Comment: @samMurphy as far as usage, the dataload event listener works the same as any other event (map.on(event, function)). As far as an interesting use case, that's up to you developers :)

Answer (score 1):

Bit late, but you can use the 'on' listeners on addLayer and addSource.

```
map.addLayer({
    id: 'layerID',
    source: 'sourceID',
    type: 'fill',
}).on('load', () => {
  // do your calculations here
})
```